# How to load Linux module while debugging Linux kernel with QEMU and gdb?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

I am trying to debug the function "apply_relocate_add" in the Linux kernel with QEMU and gdb.
This function called when the kernel loads new module.

Qemu command:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic -append "console=ttyS0 nokaslr" -initrd ramdisk.img -m 512 -s -S
```

---

```
(gdb) b apply_relocate_add
(gdb) c
```

But the breakpoint not triggered. I think that the kernel doesn't load modules. How can I load modules and debug this function?

Comment: You need to let Gdb know that there are additional symbols. I think you may find on Internet the example of Gdb plugin script to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have put any usable modules into guest, like in ramdisk.img? @0andriy This is not a symbol issue since apply_relocate_add is a kernel symbol.